# load csv tree structure in JAVA Swing

Tags: java, swing, csv, jtree

I have a csv that holds a tree structure in the following way:

```
Root;;;;;;;
;Cat1;;;;;;
;;Sub1;;;;;
;;Sub2;;;;;
;;Sub3;;;;;
;Cat2;;;;;;
;;Sub4;;;;;
;;;SSb1;;;;
```

I want to load this structure in JAVA and display it in a JTree.

I use opencsv to parse the strcuture and create a Tree on the fly. This is what it looks like:

```
public static DefaultMutableTreeNode root = null;
public static DefaultMutableTreeNode pointer = null;
public static DefaultMutableTreeNode temp = null;
public static int index = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CSV csv = CSV
            .separator(';')  // delimiter of fields
            .quote('"')      // quote character
            .create();       // new instance is immutable



    csv.read("MyCSV.csv", new CSVReadProc() {
        public void procRow(int rowIndex, String... values) {
            if (root == null) {
                root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(values[0]);
                pointer = root;
                index = 1;
            } else {
                for(int i = 0; i<values.length;i++) {

                    if (!values[i].isEmpty() && (i+1)<values.length) {
                        if (index == i) {

                        } else if (index < i) {
                            pointer = temp;
                            index = i;
                        }
                        temp = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(values[i]);
                        pointer.add(temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Of course this won't work because the pointer doesn't behave the right way (one pointer is too less). I thought a solution would be to create an array holding all "last" parents in each layer (if e.g. the parser is at Sub4 the array would be [root,Cat2].)
Is there a smarter solution for this problem?

(static definition is just for quick test reasons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Map<Integer, TreeNode>`

The key would be the deep index of the object and the TreeNode would be the last for that index.
Then you can take `index-1` as a parent.

```
Root;;;;;;; --> [{1,Root}] i=1
;Cat1;;;;;; --> [{1,Root},{2,Cat1}] --> i=2 --> Parent : Root
;;Sub1;;;;; --> [{1,Root},{2,Cat1},{3,Sub1}] --> i=3 --> Parent : Cat1
;;Sub2;;;;; --> [{1,Root},{2,Cat1},{3,Sub2}] --> i=3 --> Parent : Cat1
;;Sub3;;;;; --> [{1,Root},{2,Cat1},{3,Sub3}] --> i=3 --> Parent : Cat1
;Cat2;;;;;; --> [{1,Root},{2,Cat2},{3,Sub2}] --> i=2 --> Parent : Root
;;Sub4;;;;; --> [{1,Root},{2,Cat2},{3,Sub4}] --> i=3 --> Parent : Cat2
;;;SSb1;;;; --> [{1,Root},{2,Cat2},{3,Sub4},{4,SSb1}] --> i=4 --> Parent : Sub4
```

Comment: wow that is really a nice solution! Thank you very much! By the way: it is really a cool feature that HashMap takes just the "newest" object if there are more objects with the same key in the map.